# Svelte App Won't Render my Data in the Browser

Tags: javascript, json, rest, svelte, sveltekit

I'm pretty new to Svelte and I'm trying to render my data object in the browser. I'm not sure what's going on as the backend seems to be okay and I'm able to print the data object in the console.

I have a backend flask api that reads the following url

https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/

That's up and working fine. If you look it up you can see what the json looks like

This is the top half of my index.svelte file:

```
<script>

let data = []

async function initFetchSolarSystemData() {
 let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/solar-system/gravity");
 data = await response.json();

console.log("data", data)
console.log(["id", data.bodies[0].id])
console.log(["gravity", data.bodies[0].gravity])
console.log(["bodies", data.bodies.length])
}

initFetchSolarSystemData()

</script>
```

So when it runs, I can see values in the console like:

```
['id', 'lune']
['gravity', 1.62]
'bodies', 287]
```

So that seems to be working fine as well. Here is the bottom portion of the file where I believe the error is stemming from:

```
<section>

    {#if data.length}
        {#each data.bodies as item}

            <div class="gravity">
              <h1 id="item">
                {item.gravity}
              </h1>
            </div>

        {/each}
    {/if}

</section>
```

When the I run the script, I get no errors in the console. Nothing renders. If I replace this line:

```
 {#if data.length}
```

with

```
{#if data.bodies.length}
```

I get:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Which I'm confused about because these values are being read earlier above in the file.

I think I'm missing something here, and any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:** There's an `Array`/`Object` mix-up; change the `{#if data.length}` to `{#if data.bodies?.length}`.

### Problem

> When the I run the script, I get no errors in the console. Nothing renders.

When the `{#if data.length}` gets first evaluated, the `data` variable still holds the initial empty array, so the `#if` gets a falsy `0`.

This is also why replacing the `{#if data.length}` with `{#if data.bodies.length}` results in an error — `data.bodies` is undefined, so `length` lookup fails.

Later, when the `fetch` completes, the `data` is assigned an `Object`, so the `{#if data.length}` gets this time a falsy `undefined`.

As such, both before and after the `fetch` — nothing renders.

---

### Solutions

The `data` should be an `Object` rather than an `Array`, and the `#if` should consequently check for the length of the `data.bodies` rather than the `data` itself.
Then, either:

#### #1: Await the fetch

Wrap the `<section>…</section>`'s content with [Svelte's `await` block](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks) as follows:

```js
  {#await initFetchSolarSystemData()}
    <p>Loading…</p>
  {:then data}
    …
  {:catch error}
    <p>Uh oh, an error.</p>
  {/await}
```

Also, to facilitate it:

1. Modify the `initFetchSolarSystemData()` function to `return` the `data`.
2. Remove the `initFetchSolarSystemData()` call from your `<script>…</script>` part.

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/embed/lively-river-dni3l6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

---

#### #2: Get the `false` first and let Svelte trigger an update later

<sub>(big thanks to [@StephaneVanraes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11956107/stephane-vanraes) for pointing this out)</sub>

Alternatively, the `#if` and `#each` could first silently "fail" when running yet before the `fetch`, and Svelte would subsequently [trigger an update](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects) once the `fetch` finishes and the received object is assigned to `data`.

This can be done, for example, either by setting up the `data` with a `bodies` property from the very beginning:

```js
let data = { bodies: [] }
{#if data.bodies.length}
```

or by using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
{#if data.bodies?.length}
```

**Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/embed/hungry-lederberg-78pr3g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

---

I hope this answers your question. =)
Please also see the answer by [@StephaneVanraes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11956107/stephane-vanraes).

Comment: Using the `#await` is a very good proposal, but your problem description is wrong, if the OP would have assigned an actual `Array` instead of an `Object` their code would have worked as expected since Svelte will pick up that the array changed, regardless of it being async.

Comment: @StephaneVanraes Indeed, thank you very much! If only the `#if` was changed to `{#if data.bodies?.length}`, Svelte would handle the rest. I've updated my answer and added a demo for this.

Answer (score 2):

The real issue here is that you are mixing types.

With `{#if data.length}`, you are checking the *length* property of *data*, which initially is an array of length **0**, so it doesn't render the if block.

Then in your function you assign an **object** to data instead of an **array** as it was before. Now `data.length` will be *undefined* because your object doesn't have a property '*length*' and your if block doesn't render.

You are getting close with your idea of checking `data.bodies.length` because that is indeed the array you want to check. But you get into an error because your initial array doesn't have `bodies` so you can't read the length of it.

### 2 Solutions

A first solution would be the initialize `data` to be similar to what you expect from the API:

```js
let data = { bodies: [] }
```

then you can do `{#if data.bodies.length}`

Another solution is to actually only use the `bodies` part:

```js
const result = await fetch(...).then(res => res.json());
data = result.bodies;
```

and then `data` is an array with all your bodies, so use `{#each data as item}` instead.